# Borg Backup - Windows 10 Bash - access mount from windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, mount

I have set up 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10'

I am setting up a backup system, where I am using borg to backup folders.  I am going to store the borg container/repository in several places :)

What I want to do, is be able to mount the backup, and view this inside windows 10 (windows explorer or whatever).

If I want to get a file/folder back, I will need to do everything by command line, which I can do, but I thought would be much easier if I mount and then can just view in explorer and drag something etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers
Scott

Comment: Mount it in the wsl environment, also run an ssh server in the wsl environment.  connect to the wsl environment with your favorite sftp client?